# Show adminhtml form field when other checkbox is checked

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, admin-panel

I am new to magento and using magento 1.9 version.

I want show/Hide adminpanel form field based on the other checkbox is checked.

How to do this using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

As an example you have two field:

```
$checkbox = $fieldset->addField('name', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'check', 'name' => 'name[]',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'1'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'2'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'3'),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'4'),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>'5'),
    )
));

    $another_field=$fieldset->addField('another_field','textarea',array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('module')->__('Another Field'),
                'name' =>  'another_field',
                'required'=>true,
                'style'=>'width:600px;height:100px;'
    ));

    $this->setChild('form_after',$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_form_element_dependence')
                ->addFieldMap($checkbox->getHtmlId(),$checkbox->getName())
                ->addFieldMap($another_field->getHtmlId(),$another_field->getName())
    ->addFieldDependence($another_field->getName(),$checkbox->getName(),1) );
```

From above code if 1 checkbox checked then textarea will be visible.

Comment: @SaravananDS if it helps you please mark is accepted so in future it will be helpful for others